# Cis/trans with alkene substituents on cycloalkanes

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, isomers

My chemistry book is saying that the double bond indicated by the red arrow can generate *cis*/*trans* isomers:

[image: Cis-Trans-Cyclohexene]

I don't understand how this can be so, as you need to use *E*/*Z* priority rules in this case. If you go by the rule for *cis*/*trans* of finding the longest carbon chain containing the double bond, and seeing if the chain ends up on the opposite or same side of the bond, you find that by going around the ring, both options of *cis* or *trans* have the same length.

Am I missing something here, or is this a case where you really **should** be using *E*/*Z*, not *cis*/*trans*?

Comment: :/ Just put geometric instead of "cis-trans"; yeah it needs E/Z to be named, but it's same kind of isomerism!

Comment: This is a terminology problem. The bond clearly has the same kind of isomerism as a simpler system with a double bond but is complicated enough that the naming convention for the simpler system won't work anymore. I think you are right to argue for the E/Z convention here and you could have a productive debate with your teacher on the right way to describe the *type* of isomerism involved.